# Post will not insert into MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, post

I've been searching around for like 15 minutes and could not find anything that would fix this. Sorry if I just used wrong keywords or something it has been answered. Also to state this is not something that needs to be extremely secure, as anybody can view this.

So my PHP Post will not insert into MySQL Database.

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="./thankyou.php">
    <h2>Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="user"name="user" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="textarea" class="" name="feedback" placeholder="Feedback for us."><br />
    <button class="" type="submit" name="submitted">Submit Feedback</button>
  </form>
```

Thank you: (Yes I replaced xxx with info)

```
<?php 
$conn = mysql_connect('xxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error());
$user = $_POST['user'];
$fdb = $_POST['feedback'];
$insert = "INSERT INTO contact WHERE (user, feedback) VALUES ('".$user."', '".$fdb."')";
mysql_query($insert);
if(!$insert)
{
   die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo $insert;

?>
```

Echo outputs correctly:

```
INSERT INTO contact WHERE (user, feedback) VALUES ('thisisauser', 'thisisfeedback')
```

I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: the last line: "echo $insert;" print this

Comment: In general, you should be using either PDO or mysqli to connect with databases. Have you tried copying the insert statement intoa mmysql client and seeing if the query executes successfully?

Comment: You want to check the return value of mysql_query not the query. If you do so you can see that the result is false because of the faulty query. Use mysql_error to get error message.
Or even better: use MySQLi since mysql module is deprecated already

Comment: "I've been searching around for like 15 minutes"? If you deem that a long time to resolve a problem, at your level, then you're in for a long haul. You need to be patient, and search a lot more. Along the way you learn more about other things, probably slightly related as it's from a keyword search. It all helps, in one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

An insert does not, by definition, have a where clause.

Change your query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO contact (user, feedback) VALUES ('thisisauser', 'thisisfeedback')
```

OR, you can use this structure:

```
INSERT INTO contact SET user = 'thisisauser' , feedback = 'thisisfeedback'
```

Finally, this is *bad* for security.  Use a different [database API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: I said in my post I'm not looking for anything security as the database isn't important and anybody can view this information. Thanks, though!

Comment: @user3342086 - if not for security, then switch because [mysql is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to provide WHERE  in insert its not correct

it should be

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO contact (user, feedback) VALUES ('".$user."', '".$fdb."')";
```

You had as

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO contact WHERE (user, feedback) VALUES ('".$user."', '".$fdb."')";
                                ^.........here is the issue
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issues are the SQL query and the way of you check the correct execution of the query

```
<?php 
$conn = mysql_connect('xxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error());


$user = $_POST['user'];
$fdb = $_POST['feedback'];

$insert = "INSERT INTO contact (user, feedback) VALUES ('".$user."', '".$fdb."')";

$retval = mysql_query($insert, $conn); 
if(!$retval) { //<---- You must check the result of the execution
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "Entered data successfully\n";
```